# Editorconfig not warning about indentation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, atom-editor, editorconfig

I discovered editorconfig but I cannot get it to notify me about incorrect indentation.

I installed editorconfig on ubuntu 16.04:

```
editorconfig -v
EditorConfig C Core Version 0.12.0
```

In a directory, I setup the configuration within an `.editorconfig` file:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

Then I create a text file `test.txt` only using 1 space for indentation:

```
This is a test.
 It only uses one space.
I would like editorconfig to notify me.
 Because I set it to have 2 spaces.
```

When I run the command:

```
editorconfig $(pwd)/test.txt
```

I just get the config back:

```
charset=utf-8
end_of_line=lf
indent_style=space
indent_size=2
insert_final_newline=true
trim_trailing_whitespace=true
tab_width=2
```

When I open the file in atom (with the atom editorconfig plugin installed and activated), I do see the mouse icon down in the status bar. It warns me about the `whitespace` package.

When I deactivate the atom `whitespace` package, I don't see any icon in the nav bar.

Still in atom, when I use the command `EditorConfig: Show State` I get a green notification telling me that everything is ok.
When I use the command `EditorConfig: Fix file`, I get:

```
The file test.txt conformed to the end_of_line and indent_style properties. No changes were applied.
```

I looked all over the place in the documentation and on the internet.

I've spent about an hour on this thing.

I don't get it.

Clearly the indentation is incorrect.

Still, why can't I get any notification?

What am I obviously missing?

Comment: I doubt that this is supposed to work on text-files, since indentation has no *meaning* on plain text. Have you tried a code-block in any programming language or markup, that actually makes use of indentation? A simple JSON or YAML file should do.

Comment: @idleberg Thanks for the comment! I tried with html, json and yaml. I create files with incorrect indentation (1 space or 3 space instead of 2 set in the .editorconfig file). When I use `show state` or `fix file` in atom, it says everything is fine... `editorconfig` on the command line also outputs only the config...

Comment: I haven't heard about that `editorconfig` CLI tool you're using, but maybe cross-check against another tool to rule out bugs in the software. I've used [eclint](https://github.com/jedmao/eclint) myself.